# How to navigate back to previous page?

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, angular-router, ionic4

In Ionic 4 I use angular routing to navigate in my app. The forward navigation works fine. But when I want to move backwards to the previous page. It first indeed opens for like some milliseconds the previous page but then loads the root page which is one of my tabs. How can I navigate properly to the previous page? I have really tried a lot.

PreviousPage.Html

```
   <ion-button (click)="openFilter()">
```

PreviousPage.Ts

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router'
...
 openFilter() {
    this.router.navigate(['filter']);
  }
```

FilterPage.Html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
          <ion-back-button text="" icon="arrow-back"></ion-back-button>
      </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>filter</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>
```

Comment: `location.back()` injecting `Location`

Comment: could you maybe write it into my code. I don't really know where to put it.

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work in ionic. I just mean `constructior(public location: Location) {} goblBack() { this location.back();}`